# ignite persistence load data

Tags: ignite, persist

I start ignite(persistence through mysql data)   with spring, after started ,the ignite cache is empty.

but How to load data from mysql to fill the ignite cache, are there any examples.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

When cache store is configured, call `IgniteCache.loadCache()` method, which will delegate to `CacheStore.loadCache()` and populate the cache with data from persistent store.

See https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store#section-loadcache-

Comment: public void onLifecycleEvent(LifecycleEventType lifecycleEventType) throws IgniteException {
        if (lifecycleEventType == LifecycleEventType.AFTER_NODE_START) {
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ignite.cache(MyConst.USER_CACHE).loadCache(null);
            System.out.println("loadData userCache :"+ (System.currentTimeMillis()-t1)/1000);
        }
    }

Comment: I set a lifecycleBeans property for IgniteConfiguration in the spring.

Comment: because lack of ignite development experience, i do not know whether it is   a good solution to load data.

Comment: Your solution makes sense. So does the `CacheStore.loadCache()` get called? Is it implemented?

Comment: yes, it's implemented, and I configured CacheJdbcPojoStore for persistence,  tested it,  works well.  in a word, I can use  LifecycleBean to load data after node start in my spring ignite project. Thank you.